# Template not rendering properly with if user.is_authenticated for Django

Tags: python, html, css, django, authentication

I'm trying to incorporate an template tag/inclusion tag into my sidebar for the site. The main section of the page updates properly when I put:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <h1> Hello {{ user.username }}
{% else %}
  <h1> Hello </h1>
{% endif %}
```

When I try to use the same principle in my template tag/sidebar, it seems to ignore user.is_authenticated and will always show 'login' and 'register', when it should be just showing 'logout'.

The body of the html (main index page):

```
{% load Kappa_extras %}
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2" id="side_section">
      {% block sidebar %}
        {% get_game_list %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>


<!--Main section-->
    <div class="col-sm-10" id="main_section">
      {% block body %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The get_game_list function from 'Kappa_extras':

```
from django import template
from Kappa.models import Game, Game_Page
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('Kappa/sidebar.html')
def get_game_list():
    return {'game_list': Game.objects.all()}
```

and the 'Kappa/sidebar.html':

```
<div id="side_default_list">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Kappa</a></li>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      <li><a href="{% url 'user_logout' %}">Log Out</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li><a href="{% url 'user_login' %}">Log In</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a></li>
    {% endif %}

</div>
```

I checked a few older inquires though none of them are working properly. I tried putting request into def get_game_list(request): but it just said did not receive value for the argument. How do I get the sidebar to update properly when user.is_authenticated?

Comment: what do you mean by `The {% get_game_list %} .py` ? Is that an actual filename?

Comment: I think it's called a custom template tag in django. I'm working off the tango with django tutorial and really wanted to incorporate it into my site.

Comment: Yes, I know what it is. I am talking about the special characters in the name of the python file

Comment: Sorry miscommunication, it's not a py file, but a function of that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the user to your inclusion tag.

```
@register.inclusion_tag('Kappa/sidebar.html')
def get_game_list(user):
    return {'game_list': Game.objects.all(),  'user': user}
```

Then in your template, call the tag with

```
{% get_game_list user %}
```

Alternatively, you can set `takes_context=True` in your inclusion tag, so that you can access the user from the template context.

```
@register.inclusion_tag('Kappa/sidebar.html', takes_context=True)
def get_game_list(context):
    return {'game_list': Game.objects.all(),  'user': context['user']}
```

In this case, you don't need to pass the user to the template tag any more.

```
{% get_game_list %}
```

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) for more information and other examples.

Comment: Perfect! the takes_context=True approach fixes everything.